# \graphicspath Not Recognizing Path in LaTeX

Tags: latex

I am encountering an issue with the \graphicspath command in LaTeX.

I used the

```
\graphicspath{{/path/to/my/pics}}
```

However, it suddenly stopped working.

The images aren't found when I try to include them in my document. The peculiar thing is that, when I specify the complete path to the image directly in the \includegraphics command, the image is located and displayed without any issues.

This works perfectly.

I suspect this issue might be related to the graphicx package, as the \graphicspath command is from this package.

Some information about my setup:

I'm using Kile as my LaTeX editor.
My TeX distribution is TeX Live.
This issue started occurring recently without any known changes to my system.
I've tried reinstalling the graphicx package, but the problem persists.

I would appreciate any help in resolving this issue. Thanks in advance!

Marc

Comment: Please always include a [mre] in your questions so people can reproduce your problem.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out, it is the path that had to end with "/".

The weird thing is that it happened all of a sudden...